# Passing sqlite data from Python to the view

Tags: javascript, python, json, sqlite, frontend

I have an sqlite3 database I need to render in the front-end of my application on a GET request. Currently, I am able to render the data as a JSON dump as shown:

```
if self.path == "/stuff" :
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type:", "application/json")
            self.wfile.write("\n")
            json.dump(db.getAll(), self.wfile)
```

I have now created a stuff.html where I want to present the data. For example, loop through printing the JSON data to the screen.

Instead of just dumping the data, how would I pass and call the JSON data from the database?

Comment: What are you using on front-end? Template engine in python? JS based framework?

Comment: Is it possible to render it using JavaScript? Maybe AJAX?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. JavaScript have built in support of JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can directly fetch data from the database using the following link:
[access database using javascript from frontend](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/)